# Rails 3 : How to insert Record in Database using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails , i am trying to learn this technology , so please excuse if the question is dumb .

I am using Rails 3 .

Please let me know how can i insert a Record in the Database .

I am uisng postgresql , and below is my Table structure for the Students Table .

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='Students';

 column_name
-------------
 id
 name
 age
 description
(4 rows)
```

**This is my Controller file student_controller.rb**

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

end
```

**This is my Model file student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**This is my view file under \app\views\student\new.html.erb**

```
<h1>BookController#new</h1>
<form>
  Id: <input type="text" name="id" /><br />
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
  Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
  Desciption: <input type="text" name="description" />
</form>
```

When i access `http://localhost:3000/student/new`

Please let me know how can i insert a Record in Database ??

Comment: as the answer will be awfully large for showing the complete procedure, please follow the Rails Getting Started. It will help you learn how Rails works. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: @Preethi Jain: Did anything really helped you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you understand about RESTful? I assume that you know it, unless you can find it in rails guide (In form tag, you must add `@student,:action => :new, :method => :post`)
To add new record, just type `Student.create(:name=> "a", :age => 2)`
This statement is composed of 2 sentences

```
object = Student.new(:name => "a", :age => 2)
object.save
```

I suggest you use `rails generate scaffold Student` instead create everything like this. And then, read these generate code in controller, views, you will understand very deeply!:)
P/s: i am an amateur too:D

Comment: Only thing about this over create is it won't automatically generate a server id and will complain about id being nil.

Answer (score 7):

First of all you should use rails helper method `form_for` to generate build the form. Follow [**this link**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for). In your model you should receive your student data as a hash in a key named `student`. So in your controller it will be like

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    respond_to  do |format|
          .. ... ...
          #handle the response
    end
end
```

Here is a sample `comments_controller.rb` file for a quick look. https://gist.github.com/3748175

**BUT MOST IMPORTANTLY!!**

As you are completely new to this technology i would suggest to make a scaffold of a sample rails application and go through the automatically generated code.

```
# run this command in your command line to generate the codes
rails generate scaffold Student name:string age:integer description:text
```

Get more insights [**here**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding).

**Some Most Useful Links:**

- http://apidock.com/rails
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org
- [Just Another Resource for Beginners](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/27/ultimate-beginners-guide-to-ruby-on-rails/) :)

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a complex framework. That does not mean it's hard (even if it is sometimes), but that there's a lot of topics to get your grasp on. You should definitely read a tutorial to help you get started : the officiel rails guide ["Getting Started"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) is a very decent way to immerge yourself in rails.

After that, you'll have the answer to your question, but also more answers... and more questions too, probably.