# Rails 5 : How to insert Record in Database using Rails(HTML5)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-3

NOTE I HAVE ALREADY READ THIS   :  [Rails 3 : How to insert Record in Database using Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490076/rails-3-how-to-insert-record-in-database-using-rails)

I am using Rails 5 .

Please let me know how can i insert a Record in the Database .

I am uisng MYSQL , and below is my Table structure to be correct schema.rb in db folder

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161107113839) do

  `create_table "allusers", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB `DEFAULT   CHARSET=latin1" do |t|`
  t.string   "username",    limit: 50, null: false
  t.string   "email",       limit: 50
  t.string   "password",    limit: 50
  t.string   "likedvideos", limit: 50
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

end
```

This is my Controller file user1_controller.rb

```
 class User1Controller < ApplicationController
 def user1index
 end
```

This is my Model file alluser.rb

```
class Alluser < ApplicationRecord
end
```

This is my view file under \app\views\user1\user1index.html.erb

```
 <form <% @user1,:action => :new, :method => :post %> >
    username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
    password:<input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
    likedvideos: <input type="text" name="likedvideos" /><br/>

  </form>
```

If i do this i get an error . Y ?

```
<form <% @user1,:action => :new, :method => :post %> >
```

this line gives me an error says ruby expected after user n after :action n after :method . What do i do ?

Plz help according to my file names n not the file names of ppl in the link on d top. THNX

**ERROR**

```
home/vaibhav/MusicDirectory/app/views/user1/user1index.html.erb:46: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.' ...orm '.freeze; @user1 ,:action=> :new ,:method => :post ;@out... ... ^
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the actual error message, your description of what is happening is a little hard to understand.

Comment: Is it rails 3 or rails 5? I'm confused.

Comment: Rails 5 srry corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Your form should look something like this:

```
 <%= form_for @user1 do |u| %>
 <%= u.label :username %>:
 <%= u.text_field :username  %><br />
 <%= u.label :email %>:
 <%= u.text_field :email %><br />
 <%= u.label :password %>:
 <%= u.password_field :password %><br />
 <%= u.label :liked_videos %>:
 <%= u.text_field :liked_videos%><br />
 <%= u.submit %>
<% end %>
```